# Cannot get polyline to show up when coding in a plugin

Tags: qgis, python

I am creating a plugin to mark certian areas with a square polygon. Here is the following code that I am using to code in the polygons. The polygon layer shows up on the layer menu, but will not show up on the map itself.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
#from qgis.PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant, QObject
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .object_finder_dialog import object_finderDialog
import os.path
import qgis
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayer, QgsField, QgsFields, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsVectorFileWriter , QgsWkbTypes, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry,QgsPoint, QgsPointXY, QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint, QgsMapCanvas

class object_finder():
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""
    
    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'object_finder_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&labeler')

        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = True

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('object_finder', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/object_finder/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'plugin'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
        if self.first_start == True:
            #self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = object_finderDialog()

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True
        #opens PNG
        self.dlg.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.openPNG)
        self.loadRasters()
        #creates shapefile and points
        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.createSHP)
        #creates polygons on seperate shapefile
        self.dlg.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.addpolygons)
        #sets up moouse click to recieve x and y coordinates of each click 
        #want to visualize this by adding the points from coordinate list to the shpfile 
        canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)
        self.pointTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.createPoints)
        self.count = 0
        self.coordinate_list = []
        self.coordinate_listx = []
        self.coordinate_listy = []
        #creates SHP?
        
        canvas.setMapTool(self.pointTool)
        txtbox = self.dlg.textBrowser
        #txtbox.setText(createPoints())
        #elf.dlg.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(txtbox.setText(str(self.coordinate_list)))
        


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&labeler'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
    def loadRasters(self):
        self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
        layers = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().layerOrder()
        rasterList = []
        for layer in layers:
            if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
                rasterList.append(layer.name())
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(rasterList)
    def openPNG(self):
        infile = str(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0])
        if infile is not None:
            self.iface.addRasterLayer(infile , str.split(os.path.basename(infile), ".")[0])
            self.loadRasters()
    def createSHP(self):
        #self.layerFields = QgsFields()
        #self.layerFields.append(QgsField('x',QVariant.Double))
        #self.layerFields.append(QgsField('y',QVariant.Double))
        #self.filename = 'C:/Users/prashant.pradhan/Desktop/object_finder/newpoints8.shp'
        layer = QgsVectorLayer('point', 'PointLayer', 'memory')
        #writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(self.filename, 'UTF -8', self.layerFields, QgsWkbTypes.Point, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'), 'ESRI Shapefile')
        
        layer_provider = layer.dataProvider()
        layer_provider.addAttributes([QgsField('x',QVariant.Double),QgsField('y',QVariant.Double)])
        layer.updateFields()
        
        feature = QgsFeature()
        
        
        for i in range(len(self.coordinate_listx)):
           
            feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(self.coordinate_listx[i], self.coordinate_listy[i])))
            feature.setAttributes([self.coordinate_listx[i], -1*self.coordinate_listy[i]])
            #writer.addFeature(feature)
            layer_provider.addFeature(feature)
            layer.updateExtents()
            layer.updateFields()
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
    def addpolygons(self):
        layer2 = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon', 'polygon layer', 'memory')
        #writer2 = QgsVectorFileWriter(filename2, 'UTF -8', layerFields2, QgsWkbTypes.Polygon, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'), 'ESRI Shapefile')
        
        #layer2 = self.iface.addVectorLayer(filename2,'','ogr')
        layer2_provider = layer2.dataProvider()
        layer2_provider.addAttributes([QgsField('x',QVariant.Double),QgsField('y',QVariant.Double)])
        layer2.updateFields()
        feature2 = QgsFeature()
        for i in range(len(self.coordinate_listx)-4):
            pt1 = QgsPointXY(self.coordinate_listx[i],self.coordinate_listy[i])
            pt2 = QgsPointXY(self.coordinate_listx[i+1], self.coordinate_listy[i+1])
            pt3 = QgsPointXY(self.coordinate_listx[i+2], self.coordinate_listy[i+2])
            pt4 = QgsPointXY(self.coordinate_listx[i+3], self.coordinate_listy[i+3])
            points = [pt1,pt2,pt3,pt4]
            feature2.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(points))
            feature2.setAttributes([self.coordinate_listx[i], -1*self.coordinate_listy[i]])
            layer2_provider.addFeature(feature2)
            layer2.updateExtents()
            
            i += 4
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer2)
    def createPoints(self,pointTool):
        
        
        x = pointTool.x()
        y = pointTool.y()
        self.coordinate_list.append(x)
        self.coordinate_list.append(y)
        self.coordinate_listx.append(x)
        self.coordinate_listy.append(y)
         
        #print( x)
        #print( y)
        #print(x , y)
        self.count += 1
        #print(self.count)
        print(self.coordinate_listx)
        print(self.coordinate_listy)
        #self.feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(x,y)))
        #self.feature.setAttributes([x,y])
    def addPoint(self, pointTool):
        x = pointTool.x()
        y = pointTool.y()
        #layers = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().layerOrder()
        #for layer in layers:
            #if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
                
            
        
        
    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        #self.canvas.setMapTool(self.clickTool)

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```